# Angularjs2 and polymer-input form binding not working as expected

Tags: angular, polymer-1.0

I am working on integrating angularjs2 with polymer. I have created a custom ControlValueAccessor for polymer-input element. And when I am using model driver form, I am able to display values from component to UI but if I am changing the value in UI it is not reflecting to component. seems like two way binding not working as expected. can anyone help me on this?

Angular version: 2.0.0-beta.1

```typescript
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Self, forwardRef, Provider } from 'angular2/core';
import { isBlank, CONST_EXPR } from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';
import { DefaultValueAccessor } from 'angular2/common';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from 'angular2/common';
import { ControlValueAccessor } from 'angular2/common';

const POLYMER_VALUE_ACCESSOR = CONST_EXPR(
  new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => PolymerValueAccessor),
    multi: true,
  }),
);

@Directive({
  selector: 'paper-input',
  host: { '(paper-input)': 'onChange($event.target.value)', '(blur)': 'onTouched()' },
  bindings: [POLYMER_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
})
export class PolymerValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = _ => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    //this._elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('iron-input', (e) => {
    //    this.onChange(e.target.value);
    //});
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    var normalizedValue = isBlank(value) ? '' : value;
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);
    //console.log(this._elementRef.nativeElement.renderView);
    //this._elementRef.nativeElement.set('value', normalizedValue);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more code that shows how you use the value accessor?

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of creating a custom ControlValueAccessor was? I only ask because I am knew to angular2 and am currently trying to get it to play nicely with Polymer 1 as well...something I have found that has worked well was just enabling full shadow dom in Polymer and binding would work rather nicely